# Blend mode on PDF signature

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm having trouble applying blend modes on a PDF visual signature.
I've created an ExtGState ( `631 0 obj << /AIS false/BM/Multiply/CA 1.0/OP false/OPM 1/SA true/SMask/None/Type/ExtGState/ca 1.0/op false >> endobj` ) and I've tried using it on the PDF signature increment page, on the image resource and on the form referred to by the /AP dictionary.

`/Resources << /ExtGState << GS0 631 0 R etc...`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Are blend modes supported at all for visual signatures?

Comment: As you do not show how and where you use the ExtGState (*"I've tried using it on the PDF signature increment page, on the image resource and on the form referred to by the /AP dictionary"* is very vague), it's difficult to tell what you did wrong.

Comment: I removed that comment as it wasn't really relevant.

Comment: Please also *add* information which is relevant. As hinted at in my first comment, you need to tell more exactly how you tried using the ExtGState. Furthermore your question implies that something goes wrong... but you keep secret what *exactly* does go wrong.